# center 2 elements with display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have this simple CSS code:

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And this HTML code:

```
<div>
</div>
<div>
</div>
```

I'm having hard time trying to center those 2 DIVs horizontally across screen with `inline-block`. Neither `margin auto` nor `text-align center` is working.

Comment: text-align:center would need to be on the elements parent.. in this case, try it on body

Comment: You have to add a container div and add text-align to container.

Answer (score 1):

`text-align` will align the inline **contents** of the element. So you will need to apply this property to the parent of your `<div>`s.

[`text-align` - MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align)

> The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

In the case above, I guess it would be `<body>`:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fru489ng/)

Comment: Not with your current markup, no. What is your issue with this solution?